# trouble in understanding a method in java

Tags: java

The following is a method(public static byte[] bitStuff(byte[] b)) for bit stuffing of a message in java. But I can't understand the lines commented out inside the method:

```
 public static byte set_1_at_position(int i, byte b) {
    b |= (128 >> i);
    return b;
}

public static byte set_0_at_position(int i, byte b) {
    b &= (byte) (~(128 >> i));
    return b;
}

public static int get_bit_at_position(int pos, byte b) {
    if ((b & (byte) (128 >> pos)) == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}



    public static byte[] bitStuff(byte[] b){

            byte[] temp=new byte[b.length*2];
            int size=b.length*8;
            int count_of_one=0;
            int count_of_temp=0;
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            {
                int bit=get_bit_at_position(i%8, b[i/8]); //what is being done here
                if(bit==1)
                {
                    count_of_one++;
                    temp[count_of_temp/8]=set_1_at_position(count_of_temp%8, temp[count_of_temp/8]);  //what is happening in this line
                }
                else
                {
                    count_of_one=0;
                    temp[count_of_temp/8]=set_0_at_position(count_of_temp%8, temp[count_of_temp/8]);
                }

                count_of_temp++;

                if(count_of_one==5)
                {
                    count_of_one=0;
                    //bit stuffing
                    temp[count_of_temp/8]=set_0_at_position(count_of_temp%8, temp[count_of_temp/8]);  // what is happening in this line
                    count_of_temp++;
                }
            }

            byte[] ret=new byte[(count_of_temp+7)/8];
            System.arraycopy(temp, 0, ret, 0, ret.length);

    return ret;

}
```

can anyone explain these lines?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `get_bit_at_position` gets the bit at the supplied position. Likewise for `set_X_at_position`. What exactly do you mean by "what is being done here"?

Comment: I mean variable bit is getting which value? what is it? @Marko Topolnik

Comment: Just the most obvious thing: `bit` gets the value of the bit at position `i`. No sneaky stuff.

Comment: BTW the abstraction is a bit off: the caller is left in charge of separating the bits in the position argument into two `int`s. That should clearly have been done on the called side.

Comment: can you please explain what will happen incase of bit stuffing a message like: 11010011 ? @Marko Topolnik

Comment: As far as I could see, a run of five consecutive ones will get a zero after it. Looks like the demands of line coding (Run Length-limited encoding).

Comment: in the other cases, will the message will remain unchanged? @Marko Topolnik

Comment: Yes. I already said that, right?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the "size" and "i" variables, are counting the bits (not bytes).
get_bit_at_position(i%8, b[i/8]);
This line returns the "i"th bit value. The "i"th bit value is equivalent to the "i%8"th bit value at the "i/8"th byte.
set_0_at_position(count_of_temp%8, temp[count_of_temp/8]);
This is almost the inverse of the above line. It sets the "i"th bit to zero.

Comment: The "i"th bit value is equivalent to the "i%8"th bit value at the "i/8"th byte-can you please clarify it a little more? @Behzad

Comment: Suppose, you need to get the value of bit at the index: 26 (index starts from zero).
This bit locates at the bit at the index 2 (26 % 8 = 2) of the byte at the index 4 (26 / 8 = 4) of the array.
Is it clear now @user4650623?